# Why figure refresh does blink under gnuplot but not in the fltk backend

Tags: gnuplot, octave, fltk, imshow

Consider a program that simulates a slow displacement of a mobile agent on the screen, running on a distro based on Ubuntu 12.04. This is implemented by a RGB image which is displayed in the GNU Octave environment. The image is updated and then refreshed on the figure window with the `imshow` command. If the process runs under the `fltk` backend, every call to `imshow` is smooth, in the sense that you see the agent moving like in a movie. But under the `gnuplot` backend (or graphic toolkit), the process is very slow, since the figure blinks with every update: it goes blank, and then it renders again. On a slow machine you can even read on the decoration the message `Figure 1 allocating colors...` before the render shows. Since the program has to run on GNU Octave 3.2.4, and here the `fltk` backend has not implemented yet image rendering (and I cannot update, because it has to run without root privileges), I would like to know if there is a way to parameterize the `gnuplot` backend (which has image rendering in this version) to do the job without blinking.

Note: The blinking effect shows also in a modern machine, it is not depending on the processor or graphic board, it looks like connected to how the backend is configured.

Update: Comparing figures created under both backends, there is only one difference among their properties: `__modified__` is `off` under `gnuplot` and `on` under `fltk`. But a `set(handler, '__modified__', 'on')` does not produce any effect to the `gnuplot` figure (i.e., it remains `off`). Plus, when the `fltk` property is set to `off` the result is the same: no flickering at all, smooth movement.

Comment: I recommend plotting to a bitmap file and have an external viewer monitor the file. gnuplot is not really meant to be a presentation program. Otoh perhaps changing the terminal will make it fast enough so you don't see the blink. Have you tried using `qt`?

Comment: The normal course of action to stop blinking is to double buffer.  You always write the changes to a bitmap, when you are ready to draw, swap the buffers and the BLT the filled buffer then clear the drawn buffer.  Normally blinking is caused by writing directly to the screen.

Comment: @Karl The problem is that it has to be interactive with the Octave program. I bet saving/reading the 50 fps will slow down the whole process too much. `qt` works also fine, same result as `fltk`, but it is not available in the old system, `backend("qt")` raises the error `function '__init_qt__' not found`. But `Qt` is installed, because I can run the `QtOctave` environment. Any hint on how to make it work without root privileges?

Comment: @cup I can see that the option `doublebuffer` is `on` in the figure's properties. In a GNU Octave context, does this mean that this technique is already running in the background? Could you please provide some link or additional information on how to implement this?

Comment: There might be a gnuplot_qt package available for your distribution, which you haven't installed. I'm guessing you're on linux, right?

Comment: @Karl Yes, a distro based on Ubuntu 12.04 (updated). How can this package be installed (without su privileges)?

Comment: You cannot install packages without superuser privileges. Set your sysadmin on it. Perhaps google "bofh" before pestering him. ;-)

Comment: Do you want to implement double buffering in FLTK?  FL_Double_Window implements this - all you need to do is change FL_Window to FL_Double_Window.  Alternatively, look at the doublebuffer.cpp example in the fltk test programs.